# runas lower user without password

Tags: windows-7, runas

Say I am Administrator in a cmd.

Now I want to run a process as a non Administrator Account without entering the password of the lower user.

```
>echo %USERNAME%
Administrator
>runas /user:localuser cmd
Password for localuser:   <-- SKIP THIS PASSWORD
```

I know that there is the option /savecred, but this forces me to enter the password once. I dont even want to enter the password a single time.

Comment: _"I dont even want to enter the password a single time."_ You will have to. At least in the command line (or the bat file).

Comment: in linux one can use `su` there you haven't to enter the password, I search something similar for windows.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137254/is-it-possible-to-impersonate-a-user-without-logging-him-on